# Thumbnails of ImageField of Many-to-Many relationship list in the admin interface

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I have two models, Post and Photo. Photo contains information about photos, the date the original photo was uploaded (or alternatively - shot), a description, a title and more. The post contains post text and a ManyToManyField which links back to photos to see which are related to the post.

I however have a problem that, seeing all the photos' titles in list view makes very little sense, and so I must look into a way to show previews.

I have sorl-thumbnails working, but I'm not sure where to start in order to get them into the admin interface.

Help will be very much appreciated!